# Stryker initial run times out

Tags: angular, testing, mutation, mutation-testing, stryker

Running simply "stryker run", mutations are being created and everything seems to run smoothly, until i receive the error that the dry run failed:

```
22:19:29 (12628) DEBUG JestTestRunner Running jest with --findRelatedTests flag. Set jest.enableFindRelatedTests to false to run all tests on every mutant.
22:24:17 (9652) DEBUG TimeoutDecorator Timeout expired, restarting the process and reporting timeout
22:24:19 (9652) DEBUG ChildProcessProxy Disposing of worker process 12952
22:24:21 (9652) DEBUG ChildProcessProxy Kill 12952
22:24:26 (9652) DEBUG ChildProcessProxy Started ChildProcessTestRunnerWorker in child process 20336
22:24:38 (9652) ERROR DryRunExecutor Initial test run timed out!
22:24:38 (9652) DEBUG Stryker Not removing the temp dir because an error occurred
22:24:38 (9652) ERROR Stryker Unexpected error occurred while running Stryker Error: Something went wrong in the initial test run
    at DryRunExecutor.validateResultCompleted (C:\Users\avalchev\IdeaProjects\project\node_modules\@stryker-mutator\core\dist\src\process\3-dry-run-executor.js:61:15)
    at DryRunExecutor.timeDryRun (C:\Users\avalchev\IdeaProjects\project\node_modules\@stryker-mutator\core\dist\src\process\3-dry-run-executor.js:71:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\avalchev\IdeaProjects\project\node_modules\@stryker-mutator\core\dist\src\concurrent\pool.js:62:28
```

Just keep in mind that i receive Set jest.enableFindRelatedTests to false when in my config its true. If i set it to false the debuger wil say Set jest.enableFindRelatedTests to true. So thats why i removed it all together

this is my config:

```
/**
 * @type {import('@stryker-mutator/api/core').StrykerOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
  _comment:
     "This config was generated using 'stryker init'. Please see the guide for more information: https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-js/guides/angular",
  mutate: [
    "*/.ts",
    "!**/*.spec.ts",
    "!**/*test.ts"
  ],
  testRunner: "jest",
  "jest": {
    "projectType": "custom",
    "configFile": "jest.config.js",
    "config": {
      "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen"
    }
  },
  tempDirName: "stryker-tmp",
  reporters: ["progress", "clear-text", "html"],
  concurrency: 4,
  concurrency_comment:
     "Recommended to use about half of your available cores when running stryker with angular",
  coverageAnalysis: "perTest",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Stryker configuration file, I have added the `timeoutMS` setting to increase the time each test uses.  I set it to 30 seconds (30000).

```
timeoutMS: 30000   // Use extended timeoutMs for test run to remove Time Out Results
```

Answer (score 1):

For the angular users
In the documentation you can see two options for install use this
**npm install --save-dev @stryker-mutator/core**

Then it will work